# How many lines should a class contain?

Tags: .net, coding-style

I have seen the Ndepend rule of having a method more than 30 lines is bad. Does the same apply to a class?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such reasonable guideline for a class or type. The type will be as long as it needs to be to meet the goals of its responsibilities.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a good or bad measure of "lines of code" or "number of members" in a class. Just to better emphasize Jeff's point, good class design should follow a SOLID programming standard instead.

More information on that concept can be found here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29

Methods are asked to be shorter in design due to a sincere likelihood that most lengthy methods can be refactored into smaller ones.

Answer (score 1):

No more lines than is necessary.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, verbatim.

Comment: How does one identify and remove unnecessary lines?